# From address variables to google maps

Tags: javascript, php, location, maps

When people sign up on my site, they type in their Streetname. I want to insert a map that can generate their location. I have got the PHP variables but how do insert them into the Google Javascript code, that can generate that specific location on a map. I have tried reading some of the Google maps developer, and made my own API key, but i have no clue how to get forward from this point.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM submitted WHERE id ='$id'";
$sql_run = $db->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_run);

$city= $row["city"];
$street= $row["streetname"];
```

Comment: Start by reading the docs at [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: You are looking to generate map or only latitude longitude?

Comment: What i have read i need to convert the city and streetname to an latitude longitude and then generate a map from that point. I need some help with the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot address on map follow these steps :

Step 1: Include google maps API script file

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
```

Step 2: Create a map element

```
<div id="map" style="height: 550px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Step 3 : Code to declare map elements and for geocoding of address to plot marker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ====== Create map objects ======
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// ====== Geocoding ======
function getAddress(search) {
    geo.geocode({address:search}, function (results,status)
      { 
        // If that was successful
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          // Lets assume that the first marker is the one we want
          var p = results[0].geometry.location;
          var lat=p.lat();
          var lng=p.lng();
          // Output the data
          createMarker(search,lat,lng);
        }
        // ====== Decode the error status ======
        else {
            alert('Something went wrong. Please Try again.');
        }
      }
    );
}


// ======= Function to create a marker
function createMarker(location,lat,lng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng), 
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        alert("Your Location : "+location);
     });

     bounds.extend(marker.position); 
}
</script>
```

Step 4: Get address from database and call the geocode function `getAddress('address from db')` in script with the given address variables.

```
<?php 
$city = $row["city"];
$street = $row["streetname"];
?>
<script>
getAddress('<?php echo $street.','.$city; ?>');
</script>
```

I hope that you will understand this code easily. If there is issue regarding this code, let me know about that.